# My line won't break because of package contour

Tags: line-breaking, contour

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this. I don't know how to prevent the second phrase from not breaking at the end of the line. Surely, I can break the phrase on my own (third phrase), but then it doesn't fit the whole width of the text and I have to make it fit manually. I need Latex to take care of that line break. Apparently, the reason is contour package, but I do need its very bold font.

EDIT: I simplified my code. Sorry about that.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}

\definecolor{MIR}{RGB}{187, 30, 16}

\contourlength{0.3pt}
\contournumber{20}

\newcommand{\MIR}[1]{\contour{MIR}{#1}}

\begin{document}

I only need some text width enough to prove my point, so I'll write some nonsenses.

\MIR{I only need some text width enough to prove my point, so I'll write some nonsenses.}

\MIR{I only need some text width enough to prove my point, so I'll write}\linebreak \MIR{some nonsenses.} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aside: The problem does not appear to be related to the `soul` package and the `\ul` macro. Hence, you could (should?) probably simplify your minimum working example further by leaving out all `\ul`-related directives and not loading the `soul` package.

Comment: You can't have line breaks in contour. The main text is inside a \mbox{}.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't break lines in the scope of `\contour`. But you can split the words and apply `\contour` to each one.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage{xparse}

\definecolor{MIR}{RGB}{187, 30, 16}

\contourlength{0.3pt}
\contournumber{20}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\MIR}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \contour{MIR}{##1} ~ } \unskip
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

I only need some text width enough to prove my point, so I'll write some nonsenses.

\MIR{I only need some text width enough to prove my point, so I'll write some nonsenses.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works but in my original code, I also use macro \ul from soul package combined with contour. With your code, I get words individually underlined. Is there a way to get a single underline?

Comment: @DanielChávez I don't think so.

Comment: Okay. I think it's great the way it is now. Thank you so much.