# Define an underline with white contour that allows breaklines and hyphenation

Tags: underline, phantom, contour

I define an underline (based on the following site: https://alexwlchan.net/2017/10/latex-underlines/).

This was my initial code:

```
\usepackage{ulem}
\renewcommand{\ULdepth}{1.8pt}
\contourlength{0.8pt}
\newcommand{\myuline}[1]{%
  \uline{\phantom{#1}}%
  \llap{\contour{white}{#1}}%
}
```

The problem with the code is that it doesn't allow linebreaks nor hyphenations if I underline a lot of text. I made some research and found that `\phantom` and `\contour` could be the problem, so I replace `\phantom` with `\textcolor` in white, and add the following (to allow contour break lines):

```
\usepackage{ulem}
\renewcommand{\ULdepth}{1.8pt}
\contourlength{0.8pt}

% contour each word to allow linebreaks
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\MIR}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \contour{white}{##1} ~ } \unskip
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% define underline
\newcommand{\myuline}[1]{%
  \uline{\textcolor{white}{#1}}%
  \llap{\contour{white}{#1}}%
}
```

but this didn't solve my problem, and now I realized that `\llap` doesn't allow linebreaks nor hyphenation too ... then, I don't know how can I solve the problem. Please help.

Comment: Thank you very much @Bernard for the corrections, I think I should improve my English.

Comment: Perhaps related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126291/list-of-underlining-packages-pros-and-cons

Answer (score 1):

Modifying what you have, you can use the following

```
\usepackage{contour}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\renewcommand{\ULdepth}{1.8pt}
\contourlength{0.8pt}

\newcommand{\myuline}[1]{%
  \uline{\phantom{#1}}%
  \llap{\contour{white}{#1}}%
}

% myuline on each word to allow linebreaks
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myulineX}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \myuline{##1} ~ } \unskip
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Then you can get alexwlchan's nice underlines that you want, and also get them to work across line-breaks.  Use it like:

```
\myulineX{Now the \texttt{myulineX} text will have nice underlines that avoid
  descenders, and also don't cause issues with line-breaking.}
```

to get:

[image: example]

However, the underlines don't continue through spaces between words.  If that's an issue, I don't know how to solve that (also see comment [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412863/19048) to the same effect, I think).